# How to check the both ID's are exist in a table

Tags: sql-server-2008

I would like to know that, in SQL server how to check the existance of multiple id's in a table.
I need to confirm that the both Empl ID's are there in a table.

Comment: write a SELECT query that checks for the existence of both IDs in the table?

Comment: You could have written less words in google and found out the answer.

Comment: Are you talking about duplicate IDs?

Comment: @Greg : Yes.. thats one i need to check

Comment: are you asking us to write the query for you?